# Integrable in the extended sense: Question about Spivak "Calculus on Manifolds" definition.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

On Spivak "Calculus on Manifolds" he builds the concept of integration on an incremental fashion:

- He starts by defining the integral $\int_R  f$ on a rectangle R;
- Next he define the concept of characteristic function:
  \begin{equation}
   X_C = 1 \text{ if }x\in C \text{ else } 0.
   \end{equation}
  And use this concept for generalize the definition of integral for a 
  region $C$, by defining $\int_C  f = \int_R  f \cdot X_C$ for $C$ 
  contained in a rectangle $R$. This concept works for all the cases when C 
  boundary has measure 0 and $X_C$ is integrable (see theorem 3-9 of the 
  same book).
- Then he defines **partitions of the unit** to generalize this concept even further. Using the concept of partition of the unit he defines the integral in the extended sense as:
  \begin{equation}
  \sum_{\phi \in \Phi}\int_A\phi \cdot f
  \end{equation}
  where $\Phi$ is a collection of functions such that $\phi \in \Phi$. Some properties of this functions are described next

> Be $A$ a bonded region and $O$ and open cover to it, it can be proved
>      that (see theorem 3-11 of the same book)  there exist a collection $\Phi$ of $C^\infty$ functions such:
>
> - $0 \le\phi(x) \le 1$
> - A finite number of $\phi(x)$ is different than zero in a open set containing $x \in A$
> - $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \phi(x) = 1$
> - For each $\phi \in \Phi$ there is an open set $U  \in O$ such that $\phi=0$ outside of some closed set contained in $U$. Let us call this closed set $C$.

---

So my question is: how can we prove $\int_A\phi \cdot f$ is integrable?

---

My understanding about the question is the following: From the above definition it follows that $\int_A\phi \cdot f = \int_C\phi \cdot f$. So if $C$ boundary has measure $0$ we could use the previous definition of integration to say this function is integrable in this region...But how can we prove that this is indeed the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I studied from Calculus on Manifolds this year, and in this section, I found that his treatment was a little sloppy. First, there is a huge error in the entire section of partitions of unity: in property ($4$) of Theorem $3$-$11$, "... outside of some **closed set** contained in $U$", the word "closed" should be replaced with "compact". So, property (4) can be rephrased equivalently by requiring that the support of $\varphi$ be a compact subset of $U$, where the support is defined  as the topological closure of the set of points where $\varphi$ is non-zero.
\begin{equation}
\text{supp}(\varphi) := \overline{\{ x \in \mathbb{R^n}: \varphi(x)\neq 0\}}.
\end{equation}

Next, to define the extended integral, I think this is a better definition (it's almost the same, but there are a few subtle differences):

> **Definition/Proposition:**
>
> Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, $\mathcal{O}$ an admissible open cover for $A$, and $\Phi$ be a $\mathcal{C^0}$ partition of unity for $A$ subordinate to $\mathcal{O}$, with compact support. Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a locally bounded function (every point has a neighbourhood on which $f$ is bounded) such that $\mathcal{D}_f$, the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure zero. Then, for every $\varphi \in \Phi$, the integrals
> \begin{equation}
> \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot |f| \qquad  \text{and} \qquad \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot f
> \end{equation}
> exist according to the old definition (the one involving characteristic functions). We define $f$ to be integrable on $A$, in the extended sense if
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{\varphi \in \Phi} \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot |f|
> \end{equation}
> converges. In this case, we define
> \begin{equation}
> (\text{extended}) \int_{A} f = \sum_{\varphi \in \Phi} \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot f
> \end{equation}

The two differences are: I only required $\Phi$ to be $\mathcal{C^0}$, not $\mathcal{C^{\infty}}$, and second, I put $\displaystyle \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot |f|$ rather than $\displaystyle \int_{A} \varphi \cdot |f|$. The reason I made the second change is because the purpose of this definition is to define integration on an open set (which may be unbounded), so writing $\displaystyle \int_{A} \varphi \cdot |f|$ isn't even defined based on all the old definitions. However, this isn't a huge deal, because later on we can show that
\begin{equation}
(\text{extended})\displaystyle \int_{A} \varphi \cdot |f| = (\text{old}) \displaystyle \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot |f|
\end{equation}
But, from a logical standpoint, we should not use the symbol $\displaystyle \int_A \varphi \cdot f$ in a definition where we're trying to define the meaning of integration on $A$
(note that we have to use another partition of unity $\Psi$ to make sense of the LHS above).

> **Proof $\displaystyle \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot f $ exists according to old definition**:
>
> To prove this, we need to show that $\varphi f$ is bounded on a rectangle $R$ containing supp$(\varphi)$, and that $\varphi f \cdot \chi_{\text{supp}(\varphi)}$ is integrable on $R$. To prove boundedness, note that for each $x \in \text{supp}(\varphi)$, since $f$ is locally bounded, there is an open neighbourhood $V_x$ of $x$, and a number $M_x > 0$ such that $|f| \leq M_x$ on $V_x$. The collection of all such $V_x$ forms an open cover of $\text{supp}(\varphi)$, hence by compactness, there is a finite subcover, say by $V_{x_1}, \dots, V_{x_k}$. Then $f$ is bounded by $M = \max \{M_{x_i} \}_{i=1}^k$ on supp($\varphi$). Since $\varphi = 0$ outside $\text{supp}(\varphi)$, it follows that $\varphi \cdot f$ is bounded everywhere (by $M$).
>
> Next, let $R$ be a closed rectangle containing $\text{supp}(\varphi)$. It is easy to verify that
> \begin{align}
> \varphi f \cdot \chi_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} = \varphi f  \tag{*}
> \end{align}
> (because outside the support, both sides are $0$). Also, since $f$ has a discontinuity set of measure zero, and since $\varphi$ is continuous, it follows that $\varphi f \cdot \chi_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} = \varphi f$ also has a discontinuity set of measure zero; hence $\varphi f \cdot \chi_{\text{supp}(\varphi)}$ is integrable on $R$ according to the very first definition. This proves $\displaystyle \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot f$
> exists according to the old definition. By replacing $f$ with $|f|$ everywhere, you can see that $\displaystyle \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot |f|$ also exists according to the old definition.

**Remarks:**

- Notice that because of (*),  it doesn't matter whether or not the boundary of $\text{supp}(\varphi)$ has measure zero. $\varphi \cdot f$ is integrable on $\text{supp}(\varphi)$ anyway.
- Notice that by definition, $\text{supp}(\varphi)$ is the closure of a set and hence closed. But this is not good enough, we need it to be compact so that the boundedness argument above works.
- If $V \subset A$ is a **bounded** open set containing $\text{supp}(\varphi)$, then $\displaystyle \int_V \varphi \cdot f$ exists according to the old definition; this should be immediate since $\displaystyle \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot f$ has already been shown to exist. In this case,
  \begin{equation}
  \int_V \varphi \cdot f = \int_{\text{supp}(\varphi)} \varphi \cdot f
  \end{equation}

Comment: I think that there is a serious detail on your proof: you have chosen a rectangle $R$ containing the support of $\phi$ in order to prove the integrability of $\phi f \cdot \chi_{\text{supp}(\phi)}.$ However $A$ (the domain of $f$) may not be even defined over such rectangle. Even if you redefine $f$ to be zero on that points of $R$ where $f$ is not initially defined, you cannot argue that the set of discontinuities of this extension has measure zero.

Comment: @rowcol of course, there's a slight abuse of notation here. $f$ is only defined on $A$, while $\varphi$ is defined on all of $\Bbb{R}^n$, so strictly speaking their product isn't defined on $\Bbb{R}^n$. What I mean is the function $F:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $F(x)=f(x)\varphi(x)$ if $x\in A$ and $F(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$. Then, $\{x\in\Bbb{R}^n\,:\text{$F$ not continuous at $x$}\}$ is contained in $\{x\in A\,:\, \text{$f$ not continuous at $x$}\}$, and the latter has measure zero.

Comment: Then, what I'm saying is that $F$ being a function on $\Bbb{R}^n$ can be thought of as a function on any rectangle by restriction: $F|_{R}:R\to\Bbb{R}$, and this function is now integrable (in the sense of page 55) over $\text{supp}(\varphi)$, since $F|_{R}\cdot \chi_{\text{supp}(\varphi)}=F|_R$ (so it doesn't matter whether or not the boundary of $\text{supp}(\varphi)$ has measure zero or not).

Comment: Why is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: F \text{ not continuous at } x\}\subset \{ x \in A: f \text{ not continuous at } x\}$? I mean, suppose that you choose an $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $F$ is not continuous at $x.$ If $x \in A$  then it is clear that $f$ is not continuous at $x.$ But things get weird at the boundary of $A$.  If $x \in \text{boundary} A$ then you should prove that $F(y) \to 0$  when $y \to x,$ but this is not necessarily true (for example, if $f$ is not bounded, even when $\phi \to 0$).

Comment: @rowcol there are 3 types of points. First is $x\notin A$. Second is $x\in A$ and $f$ continuous at $x$. Third is $x\in A$ and $f$ not continuous at $x$. In the first case, since $\text{supp}(\varphi)\subset A$, there is an open set $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ containing $x$ such that $\phi|_U=0$; so regardless of whether $y\in U\cap A$ or $y\in U\cap A^c$, we have $F(y)=0$; i.e $F$ vanishes on an open neighborhood of $x$, hence trivially $F$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: in the second case, $x\in A$ and $F|_A=f\cdot (\varphi|_A)$, and $f$ being continuous at $x$ imply that $F$ is also continuous at $x$, since in a neighborhood of $x$, $F$ equals a product of functions each of which continuous at $x$. So, that only leaves us with the third type of points where $F$ may or may not be continuous. Therefore, $\{x\in\Bbb{R}^n\,:\,\text{$F$ not continuous at $x$}\}\subset\{x\in A\,:\,\text{$f$ not continuous at $x$}\}$.

Comment: sorry* for the first case, I should have said the following: let $U=\text{supp}(\varphi)^c$. This is a set which by definition is open, and disjoint from the support of $\varphi$ and $\varphi|_U=0$. So, if $y\in U\cap A$, then $F(y)=f(y)\cdot \varphi(y)=f(y)\cdot 0=0$, and if $y\in U\cap A^c$, then $F(y):=0$. So, $F$ vanishes on the open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ thus $F$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Nice; that sounds very convincing for me. Thanks, it was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Spivak often skips many steps and you have to read every sentence leading up to a theorem carefully.

The discussion of the definition and convergence of the extended integral $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi}\int_A\phi \cdot f$ uses the fact that the integral $\int_A \phi \cdot f$ exists.  This in turn is based on the assumptions stated in the first sentence on page 65:

> An open cover $\mathcal{O}$ of an open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is
>   admissible if each $U \in \mathcal{O}$ is contained in $A$.

Note that $A$ is assumed to be **open** and $\mathcal{O}$ is assumed to be **admissible**, meaning that $A$ is covered by open **subsets** $U \subset A$.

Spivak goes on to say:

> If $\Phi$ is subordinate to $\mathcal{O}$, $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ is
>   bounded in some open set around each point of $A$, and $\{x: f \text{
>  is discontinuous at } x\}$ has measure $0$, then $\int_A \phi \cdot
>  |f|$ exists.

Implicit in this statement is the existence of $\int_A \phi \cdot f$ which implies the existence of $\int_A \phi \cdot |f|$.

Given that $A$ is open and $\mathcal{O}$ is admissible, we can proceed to prove the existence of the integral. Since $\Phi$ is subordinate to $\mathcal{O}$, for each $\phi \in \Phi$ there is some open set $U \in \mathcal{O}$ and some closed set $F$ such that $F \subset U \subset A$ and $\phi = 0$ outside of $F$.

Hence,  $\phi \,$ vanishes in $A \setminus U,$ and $\int_{A \setminus U} \phi \cdot f$ exists regardless of the measure of the boundary of A. Also $\phi \cdot f$ vanishes on the boundary of $U$ and is continuous almost everywhere in $U$ (since $\phi \in C^\infty$ with compact support in $U$).  Thus, $\int_U \phi \cdot f$ exists and, regardless of the Jordan-measurability of $A$, it follows that

$$\int_A \phi \cdot f = \int_U \phi \cdot f + \int_{A \setminus U} \phi \cdot f$$

Spivak then defines $f$ to be integrable in the extended sense if $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot |f|$ (with $\phi$ arranged in a sequence) converges.  Since $\left| \int_A \phi \cdot f\right| \leqslant \int_A \phi \cdot |f|$, the series $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot f$ is absolutely convergent.

$$$$